# How To Read / Parse Firebase Response .createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: json, react-native, parsing, react-redux, firebase-authentication

I am getting back a response from firebase but am unsure how to retrieve it. When I console.log() the response I get the [object Object] and when I JSON.stringify() the response I get something less helpful `{"_40":0,"_65":0,"_55":null,"_72":null}`

I can see in the terminal a response from firebase: `Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):[Error: The email address is already in use by another account.].` Which IS helpful but I am not sure how to get this into my code.

```
const signUp  = (dispatch) => {
    return  async ({userData})=>{
        try{
            const user = {
                userName: 'test4@test.com',
                password: 'password4'
            };

            //creates user with firebase API
            const response = config.createUser(
                user
            );
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', response.__________); 
            dispatch({type: 'sign_up', payload: response.__________});
        } catch(e){
            dispatch({type: 'add_error', payload: 'Something went wrong with sign up'});
        }
    };
};
```

The returned object has the token in it and I have tried a number of ways to get `response.data.apiKey` or `response.data.stsTokenManager.accessToken`....but no luck.

```
Object {
  "apiKey": "Aaskjdfj;lkar9V0",
  "appName": "[DEFAULT]",
  "authDomain": "test.firebaseapp.com",
  "createdAt": "1571092641959",
  "displayName": null,
  "email": "test6@test.com",
  "emailVerified": false,
  "isAnonymous": false,
  "lastLoginAt": "1571092641959",
  "phoneNumber": null,
  "photoURL": null,
  "providerData": Array [
    Object {
      "displayName": null,
      "email": "test6@test.com",
      "phoneNumber": null,
      "photoURL": null,
      "providerId": "password",
      "uid": "test6@test.com",
    },
  ],
  "redirectEventId": null,
  "stsTokenManager": Object {
    "accessToken": "eyas;lkdjf;lakfj4TQ",
    "apiKey": "AIzlaskjdf;klajsdfklfnXr9V0",
    "expirationTime": 1571170025283,
    "refreshToken": "AEusjkdfkl;ajsf;kljawSg",
  },
  "tenantId": null,
  "uid": "zU4rhnTnKoNGLlu3gctP2zLorhB2",
}
```

config.js file:

```
createUser = async (user) => {
    console.log('user.email and pw: ' + user.userName + user.password);
    await firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.userName, user.password)
    .then(console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser));
};
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code with the actual call to createUserWithEmailAndPassword.  I would expect to see a call that deals with the promise that it returns.

Comment: @DougStevenson I added the config file that calls the createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you probably want to return from `createUser` the [UserCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.html#usercredential) object yielded by [createUserWithEmailAndPassword](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#createuserwithemailandpassword).

```
createUser = async (user) => {
    console.log('user.email and pw: ' + user.userName + user.password);
    return await firebase.auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.userName, user.password)
};
```

Then you can work with it in the calling function:

```
try {
    const userCrediential = await config.createUser(user);
}
catch (error) {
    // deal with the error here if the user account already exists
}
```

And do whatever you want with its properties you see in the documentation.  The catch block will get delivered the error from the rejected promise so you can figure out what to do next.

Comment: I was also missing the await keyword so the console.logs were running before the response came back. thank you this was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Dougs answer, there can not be a .then() after the callout. It appears there can only be one callback after the function completes.